# In fixed width file remove new line char in data field

Tags: text-processing

Fixed width file has 15 fields. The 5th field contains the address; it starts from 19th char and ends at 58th char (its length is 40). Sometimes the address contains a `\n` character (new line char in data).

How to replace it with double space without any impact on the actual line separator.

I gave updated data set of file, file will have `\n` char in data for some rows only rest will be fine i.e without `\n` char, please see below example, then how to handle:

Example input:

```
01 DAVIDS 800 ABC VISAL NAGAR, ABC
BUILDING HYD TELANGANA 6000 DEVELOPER HR DEPT FULL TIME EMPLOYEE
03 ABCDEF 600 PQR NNNNN NAGAR, YYY  BUILDING NZB TELANGANA 5000 DEVELOPER SA DEPT PART TIME EMPLOYEE
02 KAMAL  900 XYZ KAMAN NAGAR, DEF
BUILDING SEC TELANGANA 8000 DEVELOPER MR DEPT FULL TIME EMPLOYEE
04 CCCCCC 200 KKK HHHHH NAGAR, JJJ  BUILDING KBR TELANGANA 1000 DEVELOPER AD DEPT FULL TIME EMPLOYEE
```

Desired output:

```
01 DAVIDS 800 ABC VISAL NAGAR, ABC  BUILDING HYD TELANGANA 6000 DEVELOPER HR DEPT FULL TIME EMPLOYEE
03 ABCDEF 600 PQR NNNNN NAGAR, YYY  BUILDING NZB TELANGANA 5000 DEVELOPER SA DEPT PART TIME EMPLOYEE
02 KAMAL  900 XYZ KAMAN NAGAR, DEF  BUILDING SEC TELANGANA 8000 DEVELOPER MR DEPT FULL TIME EMPLOYEE
04 CCCCCC 200 KKK HHHHH NAGAR, JJJ  BUILDING KBR TELANGANA 1000 DEVELOPER AD DEPT FULL TIME EMPLOYEE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed 'N; s/\n/  /' file
01 DAVIDS 800 ABC VISAL NAGAR, ABC  BUILDING HYD TELANGANA 6000 DEVELOPER HR DEPT FULL TIME EMPLOYEE
02 KAMAL  900 XYZ KAMAN NAGAR, DEF  BUILDING SEC TELANGANA 8000 DEVELOPER MR DEPT FULL TIME EMPLOYEE
```

This uses `sed` to make the necessary modifications.

For each line in the original file, it reads in the next line and appends it to the current line with newline character as delimiter.  This is done with the `N` command in `sed`.  The `s///` command is then used to replace the delimiting newline character with two space characters.

Redirect the output to a new filename to save it, e.g.

```bsh
sed 'N; s/\n/  /' file >newfile
```

Comment: @PRAVEEN If you want to clarify your question, update the question. As you notice, comments are not really suitable for pasting data, especially not when the formatting is important.  Also notice that you didn't say anything about lines _not_ being broken in the input data. This would turn your issue into something _quite different_.

Comment: I gave better data set of file, will have \n char in data for some rows only rest will be fine i.e without \n char, please see  example in question, then please let me know how 
to handle